# Dummy link in HTML to load dialog

Tags: jquery, html

How to create a dead link in html.

I need to provide a "link" in my webpage that just opens up a jquery dialog. I cannot provide a href since it loads the page. I just want the link to appear like a link. So I tried with the following.

```
<a id='opener_guid' > Click here to load jquery message box</a>
```

The jquery load works well, but the link just appears as a simple text. User has no clue that it is clickable.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Just add a href to nowhere to make the anchor a link

```
<a id='opener_guid' href="#" > Click here to load jquery message box</a>
```

Then to prevent navigating to yourpage.ext#, you can `return false` on click, and/or call `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="link" href="#">Your text here<a/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id='opener_guid' href="#" onclick="yourfunc()" > Click here to load jquery message box</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (old fashion):

```
<a href="javascript:openDialog('Dummy!');" id='opener_guid'>...</a>
```

or like this (inline):

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('Dummy!'); return false;" id='opener_guid'>...</a>
```

or like this (native):

```
<a href="#" id='opener_guid'>...</a>
<script>document.getElementById('opener_guid').click = function() {
    openDialog('Dummy!');
    return false;
};</script>
```

or like this (jQuery):

```
<a href="#" id='opener_guid'>...</a>
<script>$('#opener_guid').click(function() {
    openDialog('Dummy!');
    return false;
});</script>
```

**Note:** you have to write `openDialog()` for yourself, it's just a placeholder in the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `#` like `<a href="#" id="opener_guid">Click here to load jquery message box</a>`

Prevent the link from executing its default action

```
$( "#opener_guid" ).click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a href.

```
<a href='#' id='opener_guid' > Click here to load jquery message box</a>
```

Then in your jQuery, you'll want to preventDefault when someone clicks the link - so it doesn't reload the page.

```
$('#opener_guid').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Do other stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a real link you should use a `button`, not an `a`, that's what buttons are for, and style it through css in any way you like; in this case you seem to want it to look like a link.

```
<button id="opener_guid" type="button">Click here to load jquery message box</button>
```

and something like:

```
button#opener_guid {border:0;background:none;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;}
```

The css properties are up to what you want, I omitted colors, and fonts and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#opener_guid" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, add this css:

```
#opener_guid {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bU6wz/

This makes the mouse turn to that familiar hand we all know and love for links. You can then change the color on hover, etc as thought it was not a 'dead link'